# Treating a wasp nest

Tags: pests, insects, wasps

We have a wasp nest in a very awkward position. It is in the side top of the roof above the porch. I have attached some images showing where the nest is.

[image: Image showing location of the wasp nest]

There is a window next to the nest but not very close, it would be a struggle to get some powder down the hole.

[image: Image showing location of wasp nest in relation to the window]

What would be the best substance to use to kill the wasps (e.g. powder, spray) and what is the best way to access it, walking onto the roof would not be ideal.

[image: Image showing entire porch]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have to say I would not hesitate to call a pest control company to do it for you - they will deal with it efficiently, rather than you struggling to do it and not doing it very well, especially as that's an awkward access area. Pest Control companies are still allowed to operate at the moment in the UK, though they may not all be working - ring round and get quotes.

Comment: This would be perfect except from looking at pest-control websites it would cost around £300 to get it treated.

Comment: You need a smaller, local outfit - I live in West London and the last time I had the local guys out, it cost about £70 three years ago. Definitely worth ringing round or asking for online quotes - yours is in a difficult situation so it may cost a little more, but mine was 3 floors up, under the roof,so not that easy either.

Answer (score 0):

Purchase the wasp/hornet killer that has a 20' stream spray. You should be able to blast the nest from a ladder without having to get in a position where you cannot escape the potential swarm of angry wasps. And wait until late evening or night; this is when they should all have returned to the nest and when they are less active.

[image]

Not an endorsement, there are many brands.

Also, there are extension arms to help reach remote nests:

[image]

Comment: Or consider leaving them alone, they are beneficial if they are not posing a threat to you or your family...

Comment: Alright, I may have a go at that, they are a bit of a problem as they are getting all over the house and lots are going into the garden.

Comment: This seems like quite a feasible suggestion apart from the fact that there is quite a long distance and it would be about 2 or 3 meters in between you and the wasp nest. Are there any products that would have a long tube-like the copper ones you see but a fair bit longer.

Comment: The spray I speak of has propellent and nozzle design such that the spray alone can reach like 6 meters. I will edit the post to show one brand...